# How can I make files show thumbnails?

Tags: files, photo, png, jpeg

Ubuntu 20.04.1
Files shows file names for .png files and possibly others, e.g. .jpg
I want it to show thumbnails.
I've looked at files > preferences which is set to All Files less than 10Mb, but I'm still seeing file names and sizes, considerably less than 10Mb.
How can I make Files show thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the view switch as shown in the image:

[image]

The keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. Annoyingly easy when you know how!